# Visual Studio - Command to collapse all sections of markup/tags?

Tags: visual-studio

I use CTRL + M  + O to collapse my code behind code, but I'm looking for a similar command to use in my markup page to collapse all my tags/views/divs/panels etc.  Any ideas?

Comment: And if anyone can figure out how to make it also collapse Enums, etc; that'll garner an upvote :)

Answer (score 42):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> worked for me in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2015

Comment: Works in VS 2016

Comment: Works in VS 2017

Comment: Works in VS 2019

Comment: Works in VS 2022

Answer (score 33):

I figured out that if I Select-All, and then use <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> that I achieve the desired results...

Comment: This is **literally** the greatest moment of my life so far

Comment: In VS 2010 and later it's CTRL M + A

Comment: Albert... you are my new hero!

Answer (score 9):

[Visual Studio 2008 keyboard shortcuts](http://nerdfortress.s3.amazonaws.com/visual-studio-2008-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> might be the one you're looking for.

Comment: for some reason i get the "this key combination (CTRL-M, CTRL-T) is bound to command (collapse tag) which is not available here" when I try that one

Comment: as a sidenote, how do you post those buttons in your message (instead of just text) ?

Comment: HTML <kbd> tag will make your keys looks like a keyboard.

Comment: `CTRL + M, CTRL + M` is what you're looking for in code (collapse/expand current item)

Answer (score 6):

"CTRL + M + A" For Collapse All Open Html Content ,Vice Versa use "CTRL + M + X" To Open All Collapsed  All Html Content -- Thats work fine for  me VS2012