# Collapse html in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-web-developer-2010

in previous versions of Visual Studio, you could collapse the html blocks, but that appears to be missing in VS2012. Any ideas on how to enable that feature again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729841/visual-studio-command-to-collapse-all-sections-of-markup-tags no a duplicate but related on how to colapse a whole document ctrl+M+O;

Comment: One thing I noticed is that outlining can be broken by anything that's not strict XHTML.  So if you have a `meta` or `br` element that is not self closing, the parser will continue to look through the rest of the document for the closing tag.  Weary from searching, it will give up and refuse to outline anything.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I was having this issue too and it was driving me nuts. Turns out that, somehow, I turned off "Automatic outlining" which meant that I did see the plus/minus signs and the shortcut Ctrl + M + M didn't work either.

After I turned on Automatic Outlining in Edit > Outlining > Start Automatic Outlining everything went back to normal.

*NOTE: On some ocassions, for this solution to work, you also need to close and reopen the document before clicking on Start Automatic Outlining. In fact, sometimes that option doesn't appear in the menu if you don't do so.*

Comment: That is very wired. I had to switch ON the automatic outlining, in order to get the element collapsing to work. I will still upvote this answer because it did help me somehow.

Comment: Same as @Idrees - I had to switch ON outlining.

Comment: ditto. had to turn it off.

Answer (score 11):

It's still there. The issue is that sometimes it takes a while for the parser to visually enable collapsing.

[image: Imgur]

Try Ctrl + M + M and you'll see the effect

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `Ctrl + M + H` whenever I want to hide unwanted code irrespective of any tree hierarchy. This works great even if I want to hide my commented code.

You just need to select the code that you want to collaspe and hit `Ctrl + M + H` and its hidden now :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you open the font .cshtml, you will have go to EDIT->Outlining->Start Automatic Outlining

Answer (score 0):

Just hover your mouse on code editor and wait a moment, don't move your mouse :)

The outline tree will show out.

before and after

[image]

Comment: hey what is your font name buddy i like it

Comment: @BurakOgutken haha! the font's merged by myself, uses `Glass_TTY_VT220` and `msyh` and some style adjust,  you can get it from `drive.google.com/open?id=0BydI37B8JmUeUmVNaTJJV2FzN00`

Comment: Sorry i am first time to using google driver, the file was set to share :)

Answer (score 0):

**right click** on *html*, *cshtml* or *aspx* file in **solution explorer** and select **open with** option:
in dialog select **html editor** and click on **set as defualt** button.
open html or cshtml or aspx file and enjoy html file with outline html tag. 
:)