# How to Expand/collapose in .cshtml file in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017.
I can expand and collapse in .cs files using command as follows:

```
Expand CTRL+M+L
Collapse CTRL+M+O
```

But same is not working in **.cshtml** file? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Do the commands in the answers here work? [Command to collapse all sections of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/982677) See also [Visual Studio - Command to collapse all sections of markup/tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729841)

Comment: I tried them already, seems like none of them working. I selected whole content in .cshtml file and tried with CTRL+M+A. still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could determine, Visual Studio doesn't support expanding and collapsing for this file type.

There is a sort of workaround, although it has its limitations. You can manually select regions in a given file that you'd like to hide and press <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> (also found in the **Edit->Outlining** menu) to hide them. Visual Studio will "remember" that you want these specific regions to be hideable, and you can now show and hide these sections with the outlining commands (for example <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> will hide all sections, and <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> will show all sections, depending on your keybindings).

This isn't a perfect solution by any means, because you need to set up the regions manually. But it might come in handy in some cases.

Here's an example of a .cshtml file after I set up the regions:

<kbd>[image: expanded]</kbd>

...and after pressing Ctrl+M+L once:

<kbd>[image: collapsed]</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> collapses all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> expands all in my installation. You can see them by opening Tools > Options..., select Keyboard under Environment. In the Show commands containing, find **Edit.CollapseAllOutlining** (you can search too) and **Edit.ExpandAllOutlining**. You should be able to see the existing binding or add your own (make sure to select Text Editor or Global).

[image: Keyboard binding options]

Comment: It's same in my editor too. but it's not working for html part. otherwise it's working for javascript and c# part.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Try adding a different key combo; maybe it's conflicting with an extension or something.

Comment: I have installed CodeRush.